# Vue Global Route Guard using beforeEach does not trigger

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have a route guard that works when [calling it per-route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) using `beforeEnter` but does not work when calling it as a [global route guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) using `beforeEach`.

In my code at the top you can see the example that works when calling the `/dashboard` redirect.

But if I try calling it globally on all routes down at the bottom of my code using `beforeEach` it does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am using TypeScript.

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
import store from "@/store";
import { Mutations, Actions } from "@/store/enums/StoreEnums";
import { Auth0 } from "@/auth";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/dashboard",
    component: () => import("@/layout/Layout.vue"),
    //beforeEnter: Auth0.routeGuard, // <--- THIS WORKS
    children: [
      {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "dashboard",
        component: () => import("@/views/Dashboard.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "/add-post",
        name: "add-post",
        component: () => import("@/views/Builder.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    // the 404 route, when none of the above matches
    path: "/404",
    name: "404",
    component: () => import("@/views/crafted/authentication/Error404.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
    redirect: "/404",
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach(() => {

  store.commit(Mutations.RESET_LAYOUT_CONFIG);

  Auth0.routeGuard; // <--- THIS DOES NOT WORK

  store.dispatch(Actions.VERIFY_AUTH);

  // Scroll page to top on every route change
    setTimeout(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 100);

});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`router.beforeEach(() => { Auth0.routeGuard; })` has no effect because the `Auth0.routeGuard` function is not actually being invoked in that statement. Functions are normally called with parentheses surrounding any arguments (e.g., `Auth0.routeGuard(arg1, arg2, arg3)`).

### Solution

The route guard needs to be invoked with the [navigation guard](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#navigationguard) arguments from [`router.beforeEach`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#beforeeach):

```js
import { RouteLocationNormalized } from 'vue-router'
⋮
router.beforeEach((to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized, next: Function) => {
  ⋮
  Auth0.routeGuard(to, from, next)
  ⋮
})
```

Comment: The bug is [here](https://github.com/BenJackGill/agentcake-app/blob/175627d/app/src/auth/index.ts#L77). The type of `routeGuard` should be `NavigationGuard` instead of `NavigationGuardWithThis<undefined>`.